# Executing a dynamically created command with spaces in shell script

Tags: shell

I have to write a script that generates and executes a command with a variable number of arguments containing file names. These file names may contain spaces, and everything must work fine with or without spaces.

For example, this generated command may look like this :

```
curl --data-urlencode "js_code@/tmp/some folder/data.txt" http://www.someurl.com
```

If I use a hard coded command and execute it it all runs fine, with and without spaces. If I create the command text in a string variable however, and execute the string contents, it seems the command does not take the quotes into account, using only the first part of the file :

The script (simplified, just imagine the command string is created using complex rules) :

```
#!/bin/sh
#prepare
command="curl --data-urlencode \"param_value@/tmp/some folder/data.txt\" www.someurl.com"
#execute
$command
```

The results :

```
$ ./test.sh
Warning: Couldn't read data from file ""param_value@/tmp/some", this makes an
Warning: empty POST.
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'folder'
```

I tried different things, switching quotes style, using things like exec, but I could'nt get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Note : I should add all this testing is done on Cygwin. It may be important regarding path syntax.

Comment: @spicavigo Tried that already with no results :/

Comment: can you swap out some dbl-quotes for single quotes?, i.e. command="curl --data-urlencode 'param_value@/tmp/some folder/data.txt' www.someurl.com" ... Good luck!

Comment: I'm just having a dynamic path, which is having space in it, any remedy to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You should use eval :

```
eval "$command"
```

Comment: No luck. The command does not work, but because it looks for curl in the current directory rather than in the bin dir. (says /home/Shtong/curl does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
command='curl --data-urlencode "param_value@/tmp/some\ folder/data.txt" www.someurl.com'
```

Comment: I did, but sorry, same results !

Comment: @Shtong: I forgot to remove the escaping of the second quotation mark. Changed it in my code now.

Comment: Oh, didn't see your mistake, but with or without mistake the error is the same :)